# Where to put service classes in Play Framework?

Tags: playframework

In Grails we have service classes that contain business logic that is called from controllers.
Where do I put service classes in Play Framework project? And if I define methods in controller that are not request actions but utility methods such as int findMax(int a, int b) in controller, is this possible to define within the controller and how do I declare such methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Business logic in general should be implemented as methods on the model classes, either statically or not, depending on the context.

While there are no rules about this, utility methods should either go in their own utility class in a package, or can be part of model classes depending on the context.

As an example, a simple utility method that compares two primitives, such as your `findMax(int, int)` class, is better off in a utility class, though a method such as `findOldest(Person, Person)` is better suited to being a static method on the Person model class.

Comment: Suppose I create util folder under project_root/app, would play framework automatically pick up classes defined there or I need to put something in the configuration? What if I create util folder under project_root and not under app ?

Comment: The app folder is where all the Java source code goes, so your util folder should be placed in there. You don't need to change the configuration, Play will pick it up automatically. Any code in here will be in the util package.

Comment: I'd be interested to know why this answer has had a downvote.

Answer (score 2):

There are no rules for this. I personally would put utility-methods in utility-classes. Utility-classes and service-classes should follow the normal package-rules, i.e. `com.stackoverflow.services.statistic.UsageCalculator`.

Answer (score 0):

You may create package in app folder and write your own Service class or logic class.
Use this newly created Service/logic class and its method in Application controller.

Make Package in app folder:
for eg.  play.service.chiken and make new class in this package

```
package play.service.chiken;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import models.QuotesModel;

public class Utility {


public List<QuotesModel> getListOfQuotes(int itemCount) {
    ArrayList<QuotesModel> list=new ArrayList<QuotesModel>(10);
        for(int x=0;x<itemCount;x++) {
            QuotesModel quotesModel=new QuotesModel();
            quotesModel.authorName="";
            quotesModel.category="";
            quotesModel.bookmark="Y";
            quotesModel.id=x+"";
            quotesModel.content="Quotes n umber ,njdsfkhwjd jr x=" +x;
            list.add(quotesModel);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Then Use this class in Application Controller:

```
public static Result entryInDB() {
    Utility util=new Utility();
    List<QuotesModel> list=util.getListOfQuotes(50);

    list.get(2).save();

    List<QuotesModel>  secondlist=QuotesModel.find.all();

    return ok(index.render("Size Of List "+secondlist.toString()));
}
```

Change in conf/application.conf file :

```
# Ebean configuration
      # ~~~~~
      # You can declare as many Ebean servers as you want.
      # By convention, the default server is named `default`
      #
      ebean.default="models.*"
```

And in Routes file:

```
# Home page
    GET     /                   controllers.Application.index()
    GET     /addbar             controllers.Application.addBar()
    GET     /entryindb          controllers.Application.entryInDB()
```